# case statement in select query in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure to load the data from one table to another table.

i need to set the column value of the destination table based on the two values of the select statement, some thing like the below example.

```
insert into table table_name
( value1, value 2,value 3)

select (value 1,value2 ,
case value3 

when value1 = 'somevalue' &&* value2 = 'somevalue'

then 'x' 

else 'y'
End

from table_name.
```

can any one help me to find out how to update the a column in based on the two previous column values in the same select query?

i have tried with the below sample example to understand but it was failed to parse.

```
INSERT INTO HumanResources.departmentcopy  
( DepartmentID,GroupName,Name,temp)

SELECT DepartmentID,GroupName,Name,
CASE temp
WHEN  DepartmentID = 1 && Name = 'Engineering and Research'
THEN 'sucessful'
ELSE 'unsucessful'
END
FROM HumanResources.department
```

Help me on this!!

thanks,
Venkat

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were very close:

```
INSERT INTO HumanResources.departmentcopy(DepartmentID, GroupName, Name, temp)
SELECT  DepartmentID,
        GroupName,
        Name,
        CASE WHEN DepartmentID = 1 AND Name = 'Engineering and Research'
        THEN 'sucessful' ELSE 'unsucessful' END
FROM HumanResources.department
```

Answer (score 1):

`&&` is not valid in SQL.  Use `AND` to append a condition.

```
INSERT INTO HumanResources.departmentcopy( DepartmentID,GroupName,Name,temp)
    SELECT  DepartmentID,
            GroupName,
            Name, 
            CASE
                WHEN DepartmentID = 1 AND Name = 'Engineering and Research' THEN 'sucessful' 
                ELSE 'unsucessful' 
                END 
            FROM HumanResources.department
```

Comment: This is still wrong, you need to use `CASE WHEN`, not `CASE temp WHEN`

Comment: @Lamak Thanks.  I inadvertently left that in after formatting it.  Edited.

Comment: @lamak: `CASE temp WHEN` is possible, but then you need to remove the column name from the `when` parts: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a651f/1

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I know that `CASE <column> WHEN..` is possible, but for this question made no sense

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO HumanResources.department(DepartmentID, GroupName, Name, temp)

SELECT  DepartmentID,
        GroupName,
        Name,

CASE WHEN DepartmentID = 1 AND Name = 'Engineering and Research'

THEN 'sucessful' ELSE 'unsucessful' END

FROM HumanResources.department
```